# packaging vs2005 project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, build-process, package

Here are the steps I take to create a package shipped to the end users:

1. Use visual studio 2005 Build the project (which is library DLL written in C#), both in debug and release mode.
2. I run doxygen and create documentation
3. I create a folder structure where I put  my dll documentation and some release notes
4. zip it
5. ship it

the directory tree structure looks like this:

```
     --NetApi:
               --Api
                  --vs2005
                       --relesae
                              --dll
                        --debug
                              --dll
               --documentation
                  --htmls files generated by doxygen

              --ReleaseNotes.html       

              --Examples
```

I am thinking of rolling out a script to automate that. But before I do that, I would like to find out the common practices of packaging  library api type of project, particularly structure, and tools used. References and examples are highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Why are you shipping debug assemblies?

Comment: Good question, it's still in beta, so we let our clients test it. Is it considered a bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a big believer in continuous-integration and automated builds.

We have a rule in our shop that we never, ever, ever provide deliverables to a customer that were not produced by a fully automated, zero or one step build (that means that it took no more than 1 mouse click by a human to baseline, build, package, and release the thing.)  These fully automated, one-step builds work by recognizing when a change is made to your source code control system, and automatically triggering the "build script."

For C#, I can recommend both [CruiseControl.NET](http://ccnet.thoughtworks.com/) and [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/).

I can also recommend the [Pragmatic Project Automation](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/auto/pragmatic-project-automation) series of books. Variants of this title should be available for both Java and .NET.

[There are lots of prewritten build servers](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) out there that can help you automate this.

Answer (score 0):

For deployment I really like [Inno Setup](http://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

It is free, flexible, and can be easily customized to your tastes.

Comment: Take a look at FinalBuilder (http://www.finalbuilder.com/) for automating the build process.